# Visual Studio 2012 breaking on JavaScript exceptions when debugging in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-9, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging a web site (not web project, unfortunately) in Visual Studio 2012 with Internet Explorer 9 and it seems to keep breaking on JavaScript exceptions with the standard `Unhandled exception at line x, column y in script block` dialog. This happens in a new tab titled `script block [dynamic]`.

At this stage I'm really not concerned with the underlying exception, I just don't want Visual Studio to tell me about the exceptions at all.

I've changed every obvious setting I can think of. So:

**Visual Studio Settings**

`Exception settings -> JavaScript Runtime Exceptions`: both `Thrown` and `User-unhandled` are unchecked.

`Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Just-In-Time`: `Script` is unchecked

**Internet Explorer 9 Settings**

`Internet Options -> Advanced`: `Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)` and `Disable Script Debugging (Other)` are both unchecked.

This doesn't happen if I debug using Firefox or Chrome, but unfortunately I'm forced to use Internet Explorer 9.

How can I fix this problem? Are there any options I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Web Essentials extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) for VS. I'm fairly sure it stopped when i installed this. alternatively you can try Debug=>Attach to=> then Select.... (but you might have to do this a lot...)

Comment: I've also "discovered" that this may be a hangup issue with IE cache not properly being emptied, you can do F12 Dev Tools, ->Cache->this domain.. it seems to get 'more' of the cach then just dumping the whole cache.

Comment: Slightly outside of the scope of this particular question, but I'm getting this problem in Visual Studio 2013 with IE 10 and Web Essentials 2013.5 installed.

Comment: Yea, that a negative for me as well...  VS 2015, Web Extensions Pack 2015 and Web Essentials 2015.3.  I still get the annoying errors from this old code.